# Get output of console app and display it in Listbox or Textbox

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, shell, command-line

how to run a process (avrdude) in C# and get output live while the process is running?

If possible avrdude displays progress bars which I think updates last line with new progress like so:

```
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s
```

I would prefer ListBox but if possible to do that progress bar and it's not possible to do with listbox I will not mind.

I have tried many solutions, but one isn't working, another can't get ported from WPF to simple Windows forms, and the one I found that worked was somekind blocked I had to wait while that progress bar fills to get shown it.

Maybe someone knows how to get full output with all effects to C# app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect the output (stdout, stderr) of a child process to the Output window in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642147/redirect-the-output-stdout-stderr-of-a-child-process-to-the-output-window-in)

Comment: It's not 100% your case, but isn't it clear how to capture the output of a console app using redirected output? Or maybe I don't understand the question. If you're asking people to write an entire app for you, this is not the site to do it.

Comment: no, I don't ask to write all the app I just asking maybe someone knows how to get that progress bar working..